# How to take vertical data, and extract it horizontally, based on flag column In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, subquery, pivot-table, aggregation

I have the following data format in Google Sheets:

[image]

I want to extract out the Quantity column into 2 separate columns based on if the Ready flag is Y or N.  The Item Name and Size would be the group By columns, along with the Ready flag. Below is the data format I would like after the query runs:

[image]

Have not tried any solutions yet, as I have been out of the programming loop for a long time and am super rusty with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it as pivot table - works fairly well. Item name and size are entered as rows, Ready? as columns and sum(Quantity) as value.

[image]

Or indeed as a pivot query

```
=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT A,B,sum(C) where A<>'' group by A,B pivot D ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
={"Item name", "Size", "Not ready", "Ready";
 {QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col1, Col2", 0),
  ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col1", 0)&
  QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col2", 0), 
  QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&B2:B, C2:D}, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, Col3 
   where Col3='N'", 0), 2, 0), 0),
  COUNTA(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col1,Col2", 0))/2, 1)),
  ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col1", 0)&
  QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col2", 0), 
  QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&B2:B, C2:D}, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, Col3 
   where Col3='Y'", 0), 2, 0), 0),
  COUNTA(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
  "select *", 0), 
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col1) 
   where Col2 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2 
   order by Col1 desc 
   label count(Col1)''", 0),
  "select Col1,Col2", 0))/2, 1))}}
```

[image]

Comment: I think a single formula solution is really difficult - can't think of an alternative to some variation on a group by query followed by Vlookup. Will post a pivot as an alternative though.

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(QUERY(QUERY(A1:D, 
 "select *", 1), 
 "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 <> '' 
  group by Col1, Col2 
  pivot Col4 
  order by Col1 desc", 1))),
  QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A1:D, 
 "select *", 1), 
 "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 <> '' 
  group by Col1, Col2 
  pivot Col4 
  order by Col1 desc", 1), 
 "select * 
  label Col3 'Not ready', Col4 'Ready'", 1), 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, but the other answer showed more flexibility, so I went with it for the chosen answer.  This still could be helpful for people looking in the future.